# Cannot import python http module for twisted.web

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, twisted, twisted.web

I am trying to execute a python program that uses twisted web, but for some reason it cannot import http.  I am new to this and I am not really familiar enough to solve this issue.  I have done some googling and I can't really find anything that seems relevant to this particular issue, only some vaguely similar things that don't seem to resolve the issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 27, in <module>
    from twisted.web import http
ImportError: cannot import name http
```

OS: CentOS 5.9
Python version: 2.7.5

```
$ yum list installed | grep twisted
python-twisted-core.i386              2.5.0-4.el5                      installed
python-twisted-web.i386               0.7.0-1.el5                      installed
```

Here is what the import looks like:

```
 from twisted.web import http
```

Comment: Are you able to `import twisted` to start with?

Comment: I added import twisted at the beginning of the file, it did not complain.  I assume that means it imports fine?

Comment: and then what does `python -c "import twisted; print twisted.version"` give you?

Comment: python -c "import twisted; print twisted.version"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'

Comment: I suspect you have a very old version of Twisted.

Comment: I am trying to upgrade the version of Twisted core and twisted web and I get "twisted.python.dist module not found."

Comment: I successfully upgraded twisted core/web to 13.1.0 and have moved past this error.  Seems I am also missing the openssl module, gotta dig that up now too.

Comment: Updated openssl and installed pyOpenSSL and everything is good now.  Thank you for your recommendations.

Comment: Twisted Web (and twisted.web.http) has been part of Twisted since around version 0.0.1 - so "old Twisted" is not the explanation for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is ensure everything is set up properly by not relying on any system-wide, potentially out-of-date installations of Twisted:

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
...
$ cd your/project/dir
$ virtualenv venv
...
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ pip install Twisted
...
$ python -c "import twisted; print twisted.version"
... should print: Version('twisted', 13, 1, 0)
$ python -c "import twisted.web.http"
... should work without ImportError
```

Comment: `sudo pip install ...` - always the beginning of interesting times.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone How else do you suggest virtualenv should be installed?

Comment: From an operating system package, obviously.  Failing that, using pip *without* `sudo` and installing it beneath ~/.local.

Comment: It was already pointed out - do not use 'sudo pip install', but either use an operating system package or install locally without the use of 'sudo'.  I will retract my downvote if the answer is modified to reflect better package management practices.

Comment: @rdb: you gotta be kidding me—this question is about Python/Twisted, not pkg mgmt; also, there is no definitive answer as to which is better: `sudo pip` or OS pkgs—I personally *always* prefer Python packages vs OS packages.